# Firebase: Update item in list binding using AngularFire2

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

According to the [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md) documentation the following can be done when you wan't to update a item in a list :

```
const items = af.database.list('/items');
// to get a key, check the Example app below
items.update('key-of-some-data', { size: newSize });
```

But is is possible to update an item in the list, without having to specify key:values for the object like this?

```
items.update('key-of-some-data', item);
```

In [angularfire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#addnewdata) this is possible to do like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list">
<input type="text" ng-model="item.title" ng-change="list.$save(item)" />
</li>
```

Thanks for taking your time to read this question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implementation of `update` looks like [this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.8/src/database/firebase_list_observable.ts#L33-L40):

```ts
update(item: FirebaseOperation, value: Object): firebase.Promise<void> {
  return this._checkOperationCases(item, {
    stringCase: () => this.$ref.ref.child(<string>item).update(value),
    firebaseCase: () => (<firebase.database.Reference>item).update(value),
    snapshotCase: () => (<firebase.database.DataSnapshot>item).ref.update(value),
    unwrappedSnapshotCase: () => this.$ref.ref.child((<AFUnwrappedDataSnapshot>item).$key).update(value)
  });
}
```

So it's possible to call `update` in the following ways:

- Using a `string` key and a value:

  ```ts
  const items = af.database.list('/items');
  items.update('key-of-some-data', { size: newSize });
  ```
- Using a Firebase ref and a value:

  ```ts
  const items = af.database.list('/items');
  const ref = items.$ref.ref;
  items.update(ref.child('key-of-some-data'), { size: newSize });
  ```
- Using a Firebase snapshot and a value:

  ```ts
  const items = af.database.list('/items', { preserveSnapshot: true });
  items.subscribe(list => {
    const snapshot = list[0];
    items.update(snapshot, { size: newSize });
  });
  ```
- Using an unwrapped list item and a value:

  ```ts
  const items = af.database.list('/items');
  items.subscribe(list => {
    const item = list[0];
    items.update(item, { size: newSize });
  });
  ```

(The snippets above that call `subscribe` are only to illustrate that the snapshot and unwrapped items are the `list` observable's emitted values. Using `subscribe` like this to perform an update makes no sense.)

AngularFire2 is currently undergoing some refactoring and rearranging in preparation for a release candidate. If you have a use case for which none of the above options is suitable, now is the time to speak up. The discussion is [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/854). However, for something this specific, you should create a [new issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/new).